# VGG16 transfer learning with Imagenette dataset accuracy is 0

Tags: tf.keras, transfer-learning, imagenet

I am trying to include SENet module in the middle of VGG16 network at multiple locations and then train the model with Imagenette dataset. However I am getting 0 accuracy. I am just a beginner user, can some help me to address the issue.

I have defined senet block then embedded at multiple locations
created dataset and taken only part of it to reduce the training time
Finally fit the model with train and test data

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 as Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from vis.utils import utils
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
import json
import io
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import os

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D , Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Reshape, Dense, Permute, Multiply

def reshape(img,label):
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (224,224))
  img = img/255.0
  return img, label
def reshape(img,label):
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (224,224))
  img = img/255.0
  return img, label
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
imgn_dataset = tfds.builder('imagenette')

imgn_dataset.info.features['label'].num_classes == 10
imgn_dataset.download_and_prepare() 

datasets = imgn_dataset.as_dataset(as_supervised = True)

train_data, test_data = datasets['train'], datasets['validation']

train_data = train_data.map(reshape)
train_data = train_data.batch(128)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

test_data = test_data.map(reshape)
test_data = test_data.batch(128)
test_data = test_data.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

# Load model
model = Model(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
model.summary()

# Squeeze and Excitation
def se_block(input, channels, r=8):
    # Squeeze
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(input)
    # Excitation
    x = Dense(channels//r, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(channels, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    return Multiply()([input, x])

input_dim = (224,224,3)
img_input = layers.Input(shape = input_dim)

sen = se_block(img_input, 3)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("block1_conv1")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block1_conv2")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block1_pool")(vgg_model)

sen = se_block(vgg_model, 64)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("block2_conv1")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block2_conv2")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block2_pool")(vgg_model)

sen = se_block(vgg_model, 128)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("block3_conv1")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block3_conv2")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block3_conv3")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block3_pool")(vgg_model)

sen = se_block(vgg_model, 256)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("block4_conv1")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block4_conv2")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block4_conv3")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block4_pool")(vgg_model)

sen = se_block(vgg_model, 512)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("block5_conv1")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block5_conv2")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block5_conv3")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("block5_pool")(vgg_model)

sen = se_block(vgg_model, 512)

vgg_model = model.get_layer("flatten")(sen)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("fc1")(vgg_model)
vgg_model = model.get_layer("fc2")(vgg_model)


vgg_model = tf.keras.models.Model(img_input, vgg_model)

vgg_model.summary()

vgg_model.get_layer("block1_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block1_conv2").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block1_pool").trainable = False

vgg_model.get_layer("block2_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block2_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block2_pool").trainable = False

vgg_model.get_layer("block3_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block3_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block3_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block3_pool").trainable = False

vgg_model.get_layer("block4_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block4_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block4_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block4_pool").trainable = False

vgg_model.get_layer("block5_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block5_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block5_conv1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("block5_pool").trainable = False

vgg_model.get_layer("flatten").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("fc1").trainable = False
vgg_model.get_layer("fc2").trainable = False

vgg_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss ='mse', metrics=['accuracy'] )
vgg_model.summary()

train_data = train_data.take(1)
test_data = test_data.take(1)

vgg_model.fit(train_data, epochs=10, validation_data=test_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the loss function to "CategoricalCrossentropy", technically you can use the mean-square-error function to minimize the loss but it is not guaranteed it'll minimize. Also, I see you're only using 10 classes, I suggest re-training the dense layers and replacing the last layer with 10 units.